# setting a radio button from code

Tags: c#, wpf, user-interface

I have a WPF GUI and am loading records from disk.  When I load them I need to set a radio button according to the loaded in value.

I know that this is easy but I simply cannot get it to work - does anyone know the required code?

The buttons are here:

```
<RadioButton GroupName="Membership" Content="Probationary" Height="16" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="106,194,0,0" Name="RProbationary" VerticalAlignment="Top" IsChecked="True" Checked="RProbationary_Checked" />

<RadioButton GroupName="Membership" Content="Full" Height="16" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,195,90,0" Name="RFull" VerticalAlignment="Top" Checked="RFull_Checked" DataContext="{Binding}" />
```

The code to set them as is follows:

```
 private void Window_Initialized(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    if (_name.Length != 0)
    {
        // blah blah lots of awesome code
        // here is where we have the required value as a string which needs to be reflected
        // on the GUI as a checked radio button
    }
 }
```

Comment: Can you update your question with some relevant XAML/code?

Comment: Have you tried setting or binding the IsChecked property of the button?

Comment: Typical - as soon as I typed the question I noticed the issue.  There was a typo in the radiobutton name!  DOH!!!!!!!

Comment: Don't manipulate UI elements in code in WPF. Create a proper data structure and use databinding.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Consider creating a model, viewmodel and a view, as wpf applications should follow the MVVM-principle. Then, as HighCore already said, you can easily bind your data to the view.

Answer (score 0):

Modify your xaml like this:

```
<RadioButton GroupName="Membership" Content="Probationary" Height="16" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="RProbationary" VerticalAlignment="Top" IsChecked="True" />

    <RadioButton GroupName="Membership" Content="Full" Height="16" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Name="RFull" VerticalAlignment="Top" IsChecked="{Binding RFull_Checked}" />
```

Modify your c# code like this:

```
public bool RFull_Checked
    {
        get { return (bool)GetValue(RFull_CheckedProperty); }
        set { SetValue(RFull_CheckedProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for RFull_Checked.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty RFull_CheckedProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("RFull_Checked", typeof(bool), typeof(MainWindow), new PropertyMetadata(false));


    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = this;
    }
    string _name = "bla";
    private void Window_Initialized(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (_name.Length != 0)
        {
           RFull_Checked = true;
        }
    }
```